# C#: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I always get the following error:
"Input string was not in a correct format."

when I try to convert a string from a label to an integer. I am sure that there is a string in the label. This is my code

C#

```
protected void btnBestel_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bestelling = new OrderBO();
    bestelling.Adress = txtAdress.Text;
    bestelling.Amount = Int32.Parse(lblAmount.Text);
    bestelling.BookID = bookID;

}
```

.aspx

```
<table width="650">
    <tr class="txtBox">
        <td>
            Boek
        </td>
        <td>
            Prijs
        </td>
        <td>
            Aantal
        </td>
        <td>
            Korting
        </td>
        <td>
            Totale Prijs
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTitelBestel" runat="server" Text="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPriceBestel" runat="server" Text="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdress" runat="server" Text="Belgium" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblKorting" runat="server" Text="-10%" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text="20"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I also tried Convert.ToInt32(lblAmount.Text);

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, 
Vincent

Comment: What does `OrderBO` look like?

Comment: If you set breakpoint on the third line of your code, whats the value in lblAmount.Tex? I'd say that that is not a number...

Answer (score 3):

The value in `lblAmount.Text` isn't convertible to an Integer, i.e. it contains non-numerical data.

If you set a breakpoint on the line:

```
bestelling = new OrderBO();
```

And then hover the mouse of `lblAmount.Text`, what value is in it?

It's worth mentioning that [Convert.ToInt32 is more forgiving](http://anuviswan.blogspot.com/2006/03/intparse-vs-converttoint32.html), and may be worth a try. Although if you're expecting there to be a valid numerical value in `lblAmount.Text`, then changing to Convert.ToInt32 wouldn't be the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
int test = int.MinValue;
if(!Int32.TryParse(lblAmount.Text, out test))
  throw new InvalidOperationException("There's your problem: " + lblAmount.Text);
```

Of course, you may want to just log that if your issue only comes about during production. Otherwise debug it and you'll see what's going on.

Most likely you're getting a null, empty, or non-numeric value in lblAmount (lbl?  VB6 much?).  So if you want to prevent the problem, try

```
int test = int.MinValue;
if(!Int32.TryParse(lblAmount.Text, out test))
  test = 0;
bestelling.Amount = test;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is fine. It should work if it is as you mention.

Make sure that **lblAmount.Text** contain integer value. You might be change it's value to non integer some were in the code. rest seem fine.

Comment: I ran a test on the code supplied here myself. Integer parsing lblAmount returns "20", so it must indeed be resultant from somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug and check at runtime what is actial value in `lblAmount.Text`. This might answer your question.